# Insert info from table to appear after text

Tags: sql

```
CASE WHEN system_type__c IS NOT NULL 
THEN 'Please setup a new system [' + system_type__c + '] for new employee ' + 'New_Employee_Name__c' ELSE '' END AS SystemTypeDesc,
```

My code isn't working correctly.  I want the text that is inputted into the `New_Employee_Name__c` field to be added after 'Please setup a new system' text

I got the `system_type__c` field to input correctly.

Comment: Is `New_Employee_Name__c` coming from a table in your query, or is it supposed to be a host variable, or what?  Also, you may wish to add your dialect tag, as I don't recognize this off hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes from **New_Employee_Name__c**. The single quotes signify a literal string.

```
CASE WHEN system_type__c IS NOT NULL THEN 
    'Please setup a new system [' + 
    system_type__c + 
    '] for new employee ' + 
    New_Employee_Name__c 
ELSE '' 
END AS SystemTypeDesc,
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the quotes away from around 'New_Employee_Name__c' ?

Answer (score 1):

Take the quotes off the field name.

`CASE WHEN system_type__c IS NOT NULL THEN 'Please setup a new system [' + system_type__c + '] for new employee ' + New_Employee_Name__c ELSE '' END AS SystemTypeDesc,`

Answer (score 1):

take the quotes off the field name:

```
CASE WHEN system_type__c IS NOT NULL 
    THEN 'Please setup a new system [' + system_type__c + '] for new employee ' + New_Employee_Name__c ELSE '' END AS SystemTypeDesc,
```